# How To Calculate Time Left For The Day

Tags: google-sheets

I have used formula "=TEXT( NOW() , "HH:mm" )" for the current time of the day.

What formula can I use to calculate the time that is left till the end of the day, 12am?

Say the current time now is 7:12pm. I would like to have a formula that would be able to calculate that I only have 4:48 hours left till 12am.

Answer (score 2):

Try `=TEXT(1 - NOW()), "HH:mm")`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `TIMEVALUE`

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350

Which returns the fraction of a day that a time represents. So you can chain it with `NOW`.

```
=TIMEVALUE(NOW())
```

Would return `0.5` if it was midday.

So then you can

```
= 1 - TIMEVALUE(NOW())
```

To get the amount of time left in the day expressed as a fraction.

Then you wrap it in your `TEXT` function to get it in hours and minutes.

```
=TEXT(1-TIMEVALUE(NOW()), "HH:ss")
```